# Oracle date field saved as VARCHAR2 showing strange characters

Tags: oracle

Do Oracle VARCHAR2 types interpret any kind of escape sequences? I'm working with a system that has a UI that contains a date of birth field, but the DB saves it as a VARCHAR2. We're seeing strange text in this field on the database side; letters such as "FF", "B", "EG" that seem inexplicable. The date field can take date values such as 8-AUG-2011 or lines of numbers such as 121234. These get converted into dates. The UI does not allow text such as "FF" or "EG" to be entered. So we're a little confused as to how these are getting in the DB.

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `VARCHAR2` types do not include any sort of escape sequences.

It sounds like the application you're working with has some rather complicated logic that allows it to store dates as various sorts of character strings.  The letters you're seeing probably mean something to the application.

This is reason #136 that dates should **always** be stored in a `DATE` column and **never** in a `VARCHAR2` column.  Otherwise, some enterprising developer along the way is going to decide that it makes sense to store some custom format masks in the data in order to solve some display issue which makes it difficult or impossible for anyone to update the data or to report on the data outside of this one particular application.

Comment: My thoughts exactly - this is off the shelf software and I was surprised to see that the DB used VARCHAR2 for dates. We haven't yet figured out the reason.

Comment: Ok, we figured out the reason - the program needs to use partial dates, and the DATE type supposedly won't allow this truncation

Answer (score 0):

A VARCHAR2 column will store any data you supply (ie. via SQL INSERT/UPDATE).

Do you have any server-side input validation (ie. not javascript checks) on the input data before you store it in the database? If not it's possible some script or attacker is attempting to inject malicious content into your database or compromise your web application.

Answer (score 0):

date time value can be converted to varchar using to_char function, The output date format depends on the format specified in the to_char function. So there must be something wrong with the format of to_char function,
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510